# Выделение границ слов в тексте на изображении

Tags: java, алгоритм, opencv, распознавание-символов

Задача: на произвольном изображении, где кроме текста могут быть картинки, объекты и мелкий шум, необходимо выделить границы (в идеале - только текста), в среднем всех объектов, кроме фона и шума.

Используется язык Java и библиотека OpenCV. Буду рад попробовать что-то новое, если есть достойные альтернативы (желательно не меняя язык :) ). Скорее всего уже есть готовые решения по выделению слов на изображении, но поиск пока не дал результатов. Если пользоваться внутренними силами библиотеки для выделения границ, то, к сожалению, она выделяет границы всего текста, а не каждого слова в отдельности (на изображении без посторонних "предметов").

Буду благодарен любым подсказкам, в какую сторону и чем копать.

UPD: пример изображения:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На счет нейронной сети для выделения - да, можно использовать как крайний вариант, но предпочтение отдаю алгоритму обработки изображения.

Comment: Вы бы хоть изображение привели. На такого рода вопрос -- аналогичный ответ. В среднем, решения нет. Может быть, найдётся нейронка на гите, которая в это умеет.

Comment: https://github.com/eragonruan/text-detection-ctpn

Comment: На java вряд ли Вы что-то толкое найдёте. Хотя, как знать

Comment: Вы не найдёте сколько бы то ни было универсальной тулзы, которая делает это хорошо с использованием openCV. Нужны более мошные методы. openCV сложнее в реализации и более нестабильно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Пример](http://github.com/eragonruan/text-detection-ctpn) утилиты

На java вряд ли Вы что-то толкое найдёте. Основной язык для работы с даннымии, в частности, обработка картинок -- *python*. Джава -- для другого.

Вы не найдёте сколько бы то ни было универсальной тулзы, которая делает это хорошо с использованием openCV. Всегда будут корнеркейсы. Нужны более мошные методы. openCV сложнее в реализации и более нестабильно. С другой стороны, для нейронки нужен датасет. Благо, Вы легко его можете ручками разметить. Это просто

Comment: Спасибо, Я Вас понял. Буду двигаться в этом направлении.